# Angular 6 PWA 504 error in Chrome. Base href problem?

Tags: angular, google-chrome, iis, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I've stumbled on a weird error when I'm trying to serve my Angular app on IIS and I cant seem to solve it.
When I'm trying to access my PWA offline (in Chrome), a HTTP 504 error appears.

The setup is simple: < 5 min

- `ng new pwaDemo`
- cd in to app and `ng add @angular/pwa`
- in app.module.ts add . to ServiceWorkerModule so the app can find ngsw-worker.js `ServiceWorkerModule.register('./ngsw-worker.js', { enabled: environment.production })`
- in manifest change scope and start_url: 
  `"scope": "/pwaDemo/",
  "start_url": "/pwaDemo/",`
- build the app to prod with  `ng build --prod --base-href /pwaDemo/`
- add a application to your IIS with unmanaged code and pointing to `C:\Users\myUsername\Desktop\myAngularApp\pwaDemo\dist\pwaDemo`
- navigate to `https://computername/pwaDemo/` with Chrome
- service worker is downloaded and manifest all fine and dandy
- Make Chrome go offline (F12 -> Application -> Service Workers -> Offline)
- Reload page: -> 504 error.

I cant seem to figure out what is wrong. When I'm trying in Firefox everything works (even in offline mode).

When I'm using http-server to host the app (without --base href) everything works in Chrome (including offline).

Can anybody please help? I'm really stuck.

Version:

```
Angular CLI: 6.0.8
```

Comment: Can you try with latest versions for cli, Angular, etc.?
Also, what does `https://computername/pwaDemo/ngsw/state` show?

Comment: @gkalpak Tried with Angular CLI: 7.0.5. Same problem. /ngsw/state gives 404

Comment: I tried with `http-server` and it seems to work fine. If `/ngsw/state` gives 404, it means that the SW is not serving requests. It sounds like an IIS configuration (or SSL certificate) issue.

Comment: @gkalpak do you have any idea how I can test it? This seems like a quite simple setup but I haven't find anyone else that has this problem.

Comment: Hard to tell without being able to reproduce. I would ensure the SSL certificate is valid (for the domain used) according to Chrome (you can click on the lock icon in the address bar for more info) and try to find out if the SW is installed (and if not why). `DevTools > Application > Service Workers` and `chrome://serviceworker-internals/` may have useful info.

Comment: @gkalpak thanks, I will try tomorrow. There's no problem when I'm looking at the lock icon. I know I'm using a self signed cert. Is that a problem? Firefox doesn't like self signed, so I made a exception for my site and maybe that's why it's working on Firefox?

Comment: Could be. HTTPS is a prerequisite for SWs and maybe Chrome does not trust your self-signed certificate enough to install the SW. Browsers make an exception for localhost, allowing SW over HTTP (for development purposes). Try serving over HTTP on `localhost` to see if the problem persists.

Comment: @gkalpak Well it can't be the certificate, becuase the problem still exists on our development server where we have a certificate from Terena. When I'm in `chrome://serviceworker-internals/` I find my service worker and it looks OK.

Comment: Info from `chrome://serviceworker-internals/`

 `Scope: https://computername/pwaDemo/
Registration ID: 354
Navigation preload enabled: false
Navigation preload header length: 4
Active worker:
Installation Status: ACTIVATED
Running Status: RUNNING
Fetch handler existence: EXISTS
Script: https://computername/pwaDemo/ngsw-worker.js
Version ID: 6226
Renderer process ID: 41184
Renderer thread ID: 13976
DevTools agent route ID: 15`

Comment: No idea then :/ Happy to take a look if there is a publicly accessible instance that has the issue.

Comment: @gkalpak Is it OK to contact you on your mail?

Comment: @gkalpak I can mail you the url to our test-site. It seems to be related to the browser!? Everything is offline testing:  It works on Firefox (Both mobile and desktop).It doesn't work on Android phone (In Chrome or downloaded PWA)  It works on iPhone on downloaded PWA. It doesn't work on Safari (Desktop or iPhone).

Comment: feel free to contact me via e-mail.

Comment: @gkalpak great! thanks alot,  I've sent you an mail :)

Comment: did you solve this?, if yes please add an answer

Comment: Hi,

Did Anyone was able to find a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Check if IIS is serving your `manifest.webmanifest` file correctly (check your network tab and see if that file is being downloaded when you first visit the site).

If not, you need to configure a MIME type for `.webmanifest` in IIS - use `application/manifest+json`.

Alternatively, you can follow this option and not use the web.config at all:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/53266152/214980

What also fixed it for me, was having the `manifest.appmanifest` file in the `ClientApp\src` folder, but then also including it in the `angular.json` file so it gets copied correctly during build. In my case this included an assets folder too, something like:

```
"architect": {
    "build": {
        "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
        "options": {
            "assets": [ "src/assets", "src/manifest.webmanifest" ],
```