# PWA - Changed manifest.json to site.webmanifest which can't be found

Tags: progressive-web-apps

So the new or current naming convention for having a site manifest in a PWA is `site.webmanifest` so I changed the `manifest.json` that I had to this new naming convention. Updated the `<link rel="manifest">` tag to point to the new name. It's in the same exact location, only thing that changed was the name.

I get two errors in dev tools console. First is 404 the `site.webmanifest` is not found. The second is stating that there's an unexpected token in Line: 1, Column 1 within the `site.webmanifest` so I'm stumped.

If I change the `site.webmanifest` back to `manifest.json` and update the `<link>` tag from above, it works again. But `site.webmanifest` does not.

Any ideas with what I'm not understanding?

Comment: Try adding this to your manifest link: type='application/manifest+json'  see: https://www.w3.org/TR/appmanifest/#media-type-registration

Comment: I tried that and I'm shown there's no manifest found. Only when I do rel="manifest" is the file picked up either way I named it. Only site.webmanifest naming gives the above issue.

Answer (score 1):

Your web server may not recognize the extension .webmanifest and return the file with the media type application/octet-stream. 
This media type would be incorrect.
Citing the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Manifest#Mime_type) :

> Manifests should be served using the application/manifest+json MIME type. However, it is optional to do so.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in the top answer is probably a problem with MIME tyle.

I had the same problem on the IIS server.

Just add the file suffix and MIME type in the project web.config:

```
 <remove fileExtension=".webmanifest" />
 <mimeMap fileExtension=".webmanifest" mimeType="application/manifest+json" />
```

to `<staticContent>` section...

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49566447 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/53209327/2504578

Hope this helps somebody.