# Angular progressive web app working on localhost but not on IP

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, progressive-web-apps

I have developed Angular progressive app, which works fine when running on localhost:3004, like if i open in browser and then close the server it works fine with cached data.
But when i run it on ip i.e 192.168.33.123:3004 it open and when i close the server it does not works.
I also followed complete guide on this link : [ServiceWorker](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/debugging-service-workers/#0)

here is progressive app audit when i run in localhost:
[image]

here is audit when running on ip 192.168.33.123:3004.
[image]
]

I could not figure where is the error.
This issue is when i open browser using localhost, In application tab in chrome console, it shows service worker registered. but when i open using ip, then in application tab it does not show any service worker registered.

here if my service worker file

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/service-worker/config/schema.json",
  "index": "/index.html",
  "assetGroups": [
    {
      "name": "app",
      "installMode": "prefetch",
      "resources": {
        "files": [
          "/favicon.ico",
          "/index.html",
          "/*.css",
          "/*.js"
        ]
      }
    }, {
      "name": "assets",
      "installMode": "lazy",
      "updateMode": "prefetch",
      "resources": {
        "files": [
          "/assets/**",
          "/*.(eot|svg|cur|jpg|png|webp|gif|otf|ttf|woff|woff2|ani)"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: well take a look at this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Manifest only setting up a service worker does not turn your app in a pwa. There is some more work to do.

Comment: I have already gone through this link, and i have added manifest file too.

Comment: the service worker only works on localhost or https for security purposes. That's why you have 12 insecure requests found.

Comment: oh ok, i got it . This is the real issue.

Answer (score 1):

Update your serivce worker like this by removing $schema, my configuration is the same as your

```
{
  "index": "/index.html",
  "assetGroups": [
    {
      "name": "app",
      "installMode": "prefetch",
      "resources": {
        "files": [
          "/favicon.ico",
          "/index.html",
          "/*.css",
          "/*.js"
        ]
      }
    }, {
      "name": "assets",
      "installMode": "lazy",
      "updateMode": "prefetch",
      "resources": {
        "files": [
          "/assets/**",
          "/*.(eot|svg|cur|jpg|png|webp|gif|otf|ttf|woff|woff2|ani)"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

You have the problem because when you build into production mode your code is looking for this file ./node_modules/@angular/service-worker/config/schema.json. So your service worker will not work.

Comment: no, but i got it. service worked only runs on localhost or https, i am trying with http://192.33.33.33:3004 so it is not registering

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, hosting on Azure. But I've found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53209327/1581050).
Just add to the *web.config* these lines:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <staticContent>
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json" />
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".webmanifest" mimeType="application/manifest+json" />
        </staticContent>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```