# Favicons not showing in IIS 10

Tags: html, css, iis, favicon

I have set up a site using IIS, locally, just to test html includes and whatnot. When I open the html file locally in the browser without hosting it on IIS, the favicons load just fine. When I set up the site using IIS, all pages load just fine except the favicons- they don't appear. HTML as follows:

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="assets/favicons/apple-touch-icon.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="favicon-32x32.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="assets/favicons/favicon-16x16.png">
<link rel="manifest" href="assets/favicons/site.webmanifest">
<link rel="mask-icon" href="assets/favicons/safari-pinned-tab.svg" color="#5bbad5">
<meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#da532c">
<meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff">
```

Some digging reveals it is an issue with the site.manifest- it says error 401.3 not authorised.

How can I get favicons to work using IIS? Thanks.

Comment: do you have mime type set for .manifest? see here > https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49566446/how-can-i-have-iis-properly-serve-webmanifest-files-on-my-web-site

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/943891/the-http-status-code-in-iis-7-0-iis-7-5-and-iis-8-0 Get started from there.

Comment: @LexLi 401.3 -  Unauthorized due to ACL on resource. Not sure what that means really, I'm investigating the above answer regarding the mime type.

Comment: KB943891 is an index page for most IIS error codes. Scroll down to find the actual link to 401.3.

Comment: @KresimirPendic I tried adding it, and restarting the site, unfortunately it did not work. I now get error 500.19 - Internal Server Error. It says "Cannot read configuration file due to insufficient permissions"

Answer (score 0):

I suspect there is something wrong with `Read/Write` permission of the website root folder.
Please grant full control of the website root folder to the `IUSR` account.
[image]
Besides, please ensure that we have already enabled `Anonymous Authentication` mode in IIS site binding module.
[image]
Feel free to let me know if the problem persists.